# Classic ASP with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a html page with a form like:

```
<form id="goodsearch" action="test.asp" method="post">
<input type="text" id="goods" name="name"></input>
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"></input>
</form>
```

I wrote a separate script file by jQuery. When user input one a name of goods into form and click submit button, goods name is searched in DB

```
$("#goodsearch").submit(function() {

      $.ajax({
         url: "test.asp",
         type: "post",
         data: { "name": '"' + $("#goods").val() + '"' },
         success: function(data) {
            alert(Response);
         }
      });

      return false;
   });
```

On Server side classic ASP, I wrote some code for testing:

```
<%@ Language = VBScript %>
<%
dim x
x = Request.Form("name")
Response.Write(x)
%>
```

But nothing happen.
This is my first time write code using ajax. So I don't know where is wrong.

Another a question:
If I want mix server-side class asp with many functions on a html page and use jQuery with ajax to call function in asp, how do I can call a sepecific function?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. Just change ajax success function to:

```
 success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
         }
```